# Is there an award for Esperanto literature?

Tags: literature

Or the question could be: "Is there something similar to the Nobel prize in literature just for Esperanto works?"

Answer (score 8):

The closest to that is the OSIEK Prize, which is judged annually on the basis of nominations, and may be awarded for most kinds of published work in Esperanto, including translations and reference works.

- http://www.osiek.org/premio/

Nearly all other prizes (e.g. the *Belartaj Konkursoj*) are associated with competitions and contests, and may require that the submitted work has not been published before.